# Can't seem to retrieve a ExifSubIFDDirectory

Tags: java, image, metadata, exif

I'm trying to **extract the Date info from a picture**. I'm getting along quite good but I have this problem bugging me for 2 days. I've even rewriten the entire code once and still get it.

I obviously get an NP because I return a null in the method grabExifSubIFDDirectory. This is the main problem, it claims there is **no Directory available** while there should be one. *Why can't it grab the directory?* I'm using standrd jpegs and other formats.

The jar is placed inside a folder with pictures.

If somebody could point (hehe) me int the direction?

Package utils:

```
package utils;

import com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader;
import com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException;
import com.drew.metadata.Metadata;
import com.drew.metadata.exif.ExifSubIFDDirectory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FileUtils {

    private ArrayList<String> fileNamesList;

    public FileUtils(String jarFilePath) {
        setFileNames(jarFilePath);
    }

    // Retrieves a Metadata object from a File object and returns it.
    public Metadata grabFileMetaData(String filePath) {
        Metadata metadata = null;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try {
            metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);
        } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);
        }
        return metadata;
    }

    // Retrieves a ExifSubIFDDirectory object from a Metadata object and returns it. 
    public ExifSubIFDDirectory grabExifSubIFDDirectory(Metadata metadata, String filePath) {
        ExifSubIFDDirectory directory;
        if (metadata.containsDirectory(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class)) {
            directory = (ExifSubIFDDirectory) metadata.getDirectory(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class);
            return directory;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File at: " + filePath + " does not contain exif date.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Retrieves a Date object from a ExifSubIFDDirectory object and returns it.
    public Date grabDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory directory) {
        Date date;
        date = directory.getDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL);
        return date;
    }

    // Return the actual Date object using the above methods.
    public Date getDate(String filePath) {
        return grabDate(grabExifSubIFDDirectory(grabFileMetaData(filePath), filePath));
    }

    // Retrieves the names of the files in the same folder as the executed jar.
    // Saves them in a variable.
    public void setFileNames(String jarPath) {
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList();
        String path = jarPath;
        String files;
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
            if (listOfFile.isFile()) {
                files = listOfFile.getName();
                if (!"PhotoRenamer.jar".equals(files) && !"Thumbs.db".equals(files)) {
                    temp.add(files);
                }
            }
        }
        this.fileNamesList = temp;
    }

    // getter
    public ArrayList<String> getFileNamesList() {
        return fileNamesList;
    }

}
```

Package domein:

```
package domein;

    import utils.FileUtils;
    import utils.JarUtils;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class DomeinController {

        FileUtils fileUtils;
        JarUtils jarUtils;

        public DomeinController() {
            this.jarUtils = new JarUtils();
            this.fileUtils = new FileUtils(jarUtils.getJarPath());
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getFileNamesList() {
            return fileUtils.getFileNamesList();
        }

        public String getJarPath() {
            return jarUtils.getJarPath();
        }

        // Retrieve string from Date object of the file with the number i.
        public String getDate(int i) {
            return fileUtils.getDate(createFilePath(i)).toString();
        }

        public String createFilePath(int i) {
            return getJarPath() + "\\" + fileUtils.getFileNamesList().get(i);
        }

    }
```

Package startup:

```
 package startup;

import domein.DomeinController;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        DomeinController  dc = new DomeinController();

        // print out jar path
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,dc.getJarPath());

        // print out file names in folder
        String lijstje = "";
        for (int i=0;i<dc.getFileNamesList().size();i++){
            lijstje += dc.getFileNamesList().get(i);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,lijstje);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,dc.getDate(1));
    }

}
```

Comment: The download link above does not work... In any case, it's better (for you and for us) if you get rid of the link and the code above and instead create an MVCE as described in the help center. This helps pinpoint the problem, and will in many cases help you fix the problem yourself. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getDate(String filePath)` method is working just fine, I tested it.

So it must come from the picture itself

- Test your code with a single picture (with a unit test), make sure the `getDate` method is working for you. Do the test with a picture coming from the Internet too.
- As `Metadata` is not null, the file does exist so the picture has no EXIF information, there is no possible doubt.
- Use [this tool](http://regex.info/exif.cgi) to check if your pictures have EXIF information

Comment: I'm in the process of writing some JUnit tests right now. So you state here that my program did retieve th DateTaken value when you tested it?

Comment: I unit tested `getDate` with a picture taken by my phone, it worked just fine.

Comment: Wow, that is bizarre. Let me try something quick.

Comment: You are right, my tests did work with a photo from the net with valid info.

Comment: This leaves me at another problem to handle for which I shall create another question or search the net. How do I retrieve the date taken, without using exif. Since the pictures contain the info. When you check their properties they have a date taken. But it's probably not exif. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to realize is that not all images contain that EXIF information.  For any number of reasons, the metadata can be scrubbed from an image.

I was going through a similar issue earlier today, and this was my solution:

```
public HashMap<String, String> getMetadata(File photoFile){
    Metadata metadata;
    ExifSubIFDDirectory exifSubIFDDirectory;
    HashMap<String, String> tagMap = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(photoFile);
        exifSubIFDDirectory = metadata.getDirectory(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class);
        ExifSubIFDDescriptor exifSubIFDDescriptor = new ExifSubIFDDescriptor(exifSubIFDDirectory);

        if (exifSubIFDDirectory != null) {
            tagMap.put("lens", exifSubIFDDirectory.getDescription(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_LENS_MODEL).toString());
            tagMap.put("captureDate", exifSubIFDDirectory.getDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL).toString());
            tagMap.put("shutter", exifSubIFDDescriptor.getExposureTimeDescription());
            tagMap.put("aperture", exifSubIFDDescriptor.getFNumberDescription());
            tagMap.put("focalLength", exifSubIFDDescriptor.getFocalLengthDescription());
            tagMap.put("iso", exifSubIFDDescriptor.getIsoEquivalentDescription());
            tagMap.put("meterMode", exifSubIFDDescriptor.getMeteringModeDescription());                

            //null is a possible return value from the method calls above.  Replace them
            //with default no value string
            for (String key : tagMap.keySet()){
                if (tagMap.get(key) == null)
                    tagMap.put(key, "No Value Recorded");
            }
        } else {
            Date currentDate = new Date();
            tagMap.put("captureDate", currentDate.toString());
            tagMap.put("shutter", "No Value Recorded");
            tagMap.put("aperture", "No Value Recorded");
            tagMap.put("focalLength", "No Value Recorded");
            tagMap.put("iso", "No Value Recorded");
            tagMap.put("meterMode","No Value Recorded");
            tagMap.put("lens", "No Value Recorded");

        }
    } catch (ImageProcessingException|IOException|NullPointerException e) { 
        //unhandled exception, put out logging statement
        log.error("Error processing metadata for file " + photoFile.getName() + "\n" + e.getStackTrace());
    }

    return tagMap;
}
```

As you can see, I check if the `ExifSubIFDDirectory` object exists before doing any work.  If it does, then the metadata fields I want are saved in a HashMap object, which is later persisted in the database.  If the tag doesn't exist, it is stored as a null value, which is later replaced with a 'No Value Found' string.

Essentially, your issue here was not checking if `ExifSubIFDDirectory` object is initialized via the `metadata.getDirectory` call.  I think if you use an image with the metadata set, you wouldn't encounter this issue during testing.

Comment: Didn't I check whether it exists with this?
if (metadata.containsDirectory(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class))

Comment: Normally, I would agree with you.  However, it seems that you may need an explicit null check for the directory object.

Comment: Alright thanks Jason for the helpful information and your example.

Answer (score 1):

*(This is a general advice from the image codec perspective. It may or may not be applicable to the users of the open source library by Drew Noakes.)*

My first step is to use [Phil Harvey's ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to dump the metadata from the JPEG file in a rather exhaustive way.

Once you are sure that the JPEG file contains EXIF data, what follows is troubleshooting effort to find out why the library does not return that part of data. It might be properly parsing it, but perhaps your code didn't retrieve it from its API in the way it expects.

*(Since I don't know this open-source library, I cannot give any advice specific to this library.)*

Check whether the JPEG file contains an APP1 segment. The APP1 segment is marked by a two-byte sequence `0xFF 0xE1`.

Different image libraries provide different ways of finding out whether an APP1 segment is present. Other libraries may skip over, ignore, or consume and hide this segment from the API user.

If your library allows it, install a metadata header event handler for APP1 so that you can see what processing is performed on its data. You can then track down how the library intends to store and provide that data via its API.

http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000147.shtml

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Comment: I'm very pleased with a detailed answer and it gives some other ways to approach the problem thank you.